# Stop Google Maps reloading

Tags: javascript, google-maps, caching, reload

When we drag Google Maps to show another location, it loads map images. When I go back to the first location, I would expect that those images were somehow cached, so no reload is needed. But that's not the case.

Anyone ever managed to somehow cache the same images, so no reload is needed?

EDIT (adding code sample)

```
var _map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("vehicles-map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(Settings.default_map_lat, Settings.default_map_lng),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
```

Comment: I added creation code, but I don't see how It could help answering this question. I really have no issues with rendering the map, showing locations, markers or anything else, only with this reloading, which makes it a bit irritating. :)

Comment: I can't confirm the reload.

Comment: When I said reloading, I really meant downloading map images again for the same location :) The code above is responsible for creation of the map, the rest of the code that I didn't post here only works with markers, panning/zooming etc. Nothing releated with this :\

Comment: I'm seeing this unexpected behavior also. It seems that Google attaches a "token" parameter to each image URL. I'm very surprised since this abandons the opportunity to use caching and have the API perform much more responsively.

Answer (score 0):

So this won't be the case for all users, but I accidentally had "Disable cache" checked in my Chrome dev tools:

[image]

This is a sticky setting so it's easy to forget you had it enabled from a prior session.